# Python regular expression to find longest ORF in DNA sequence

Tags: python, python-re

I was using regular expression to get the longest ORF in DNA sequence, which starts with 'ATG' and stops with 'TAA or TAG or TGA'.

```
line = "CTGGCGACCGGAGGGCGACAACGGCGGCTGGGATGGTTAGTACTCGGGGCCCAGGCGGCCATGGGAGAGGTGCAGCTGTTGGAGTCTGGGGGAGGCCTGGTACAGCCTGGGGGGTCCCTGAGACTCTCCTGCGCAGCCTCTGGATTCACTTTTGAGCAATATGATATGCGCTGGGTCCGCCAGGCTCCTGGGAAGGGGCTGGAGTGGGTCAGTGCGATCAGCCGCGAGGGCAGAGCCACGTATTATGCAGACTCCGTGAAGGGCCGATTCACCATCTCCAGAGACAACTCCAAGAACACACTGTATCTGCAAATGAACAGCCTGAGAGCCGAGGACACGGCTGTGTATTACTGCGCTAGAGACTTGGGTGACTATTGGGGCCAAGGAACCCTGGTCACCGTCTCCTCAGGTGGCGGTGGATCGGGCGGTGGTGGATCTGGAGGAGGTGGCTCGGACATCCAGATGACCCAGTCTCCATCCTCCCTGTCTGCATCTGTAGGAGACAGAGTCACCATCACTTGCTCTGGAGATAAGTTGGGACATACGTATACCTCCTGGTACCAACAGAAACCAGGGAAAGCCCCTAAGCTCCTGATCTATCATGATAATAAGCGCCCTTCAGGGGTCCCTTCAAGGTTCAGTGGCAGTGGATCTGGGACAGATTTCACTCTCACCATCAGCAGTCTGCAGCCTGAAGATTTTGCAACTTATTACTGCTCTACTAGATCAAGCAAGGGCAATCCACACGTCCTGTTCGGCCAAGGACCAAAGTGGAGATCAAAAGGCCCGGGAGGCCAACACCATCACCACCATCATGGCGCATATCCGTATGATGTGCCGGACTATGCTTCTTAGCCGAAACTGTTGAAAGTTGTTTAGCAAAACCTCATACAGAAAATTCATTTACTAACGTCTGGAAGACGACAAACTTTAGATCGTTACGCTAACTATGAGGCTGTCTGTGGATGCTACAGCGTTGTGGTTTGTACTGTGACGAAACTCATGTTACGGTACATGGTTCTATTGGCTGCTATCCTGAAATGAAGTGTGCTCTGAAGGTGGCCGTTCTGAGGGTGGCGTTCTGAAGTGACGTACTTAAACATCTGAGATACGTGATATACCTATTTCCGGGGCTATATCTTATATATAAACCCTCTCTGACG"

longestORF = max(re.findall(r'ATG(?:(?!TAA|TAG|TGA)...)*(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)',line), key = len)
```

Somehow the above line didn't return the longest ORF, and I can't figure why.
It returns ORF starting with "ATGAACAGC".
It should return the ORF which starts with "ATGGGAGAG" and ends with "TATGCTTCT".
Someone can explain this?

Comment: findall only finds non-overlapping matches. You should instead modify your regex so that it finds the longest match..

Comment: Do you *need* to use regex? For this purpose I think it causes more problems than it solves.

Comment: how should I modify the regex?

Answer (score 0):

Findall stops consuming characters once it finds a match and then continues searching for new matches from the end of the first match, as such it only finds non-overlapping matches, meaning that if given the string "ATGABCDTAAEFGHIJTAG" it will only match on "ATGABCDTAA" instead of the whole string.

You could instead modify your regex to be something like the following:

```
ATG.*(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)
```

I tested this on [regex101](https://regex101.com/) and it finds the longest match in your string.

Explanation:

`ATG` matches the string "ATG" exactly.

`.*` matches as many characters as possible (greedy) except for white-spaces.

`(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)` matches one of "TAA", "TAG" and "TGA".

Comment: Probably should do `(...)*`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Vinzent for explanation.

The solution is simple:

```
import regex as re
longestORF = max(re.findall(r'ATG(?:(?!TAA|TAG|TGA)...)*(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)',line, overlapped=True), key = len)
```

This returns the longest (including overlapping) match.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with the `re` module, with positive look-ahead:

```
longestORF = max(re.findall(r'(?=(ATG(?:(?!TAA|TAG|TGA)...)*(?:TAA|TAG|TGA)))',line), key = len)
print(longestORF)
```

All I did was surround your regex with `(?=(` and `))`.

Smaller demo showing that we *can* get overlapping matches:

```
import re

print(re.findall('(?=(...))', 'abcdef'))
```

Prints `['abc', 'bcd', 'cde', 'def']`.